# What is the reason that the filter for None takes the "0" away from given list in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I am trying to fix a bug in python. I came across a situation where when I do something like below, zero is removed automatically out of all the list of numbers.

```
d = list(filter(None,[0,5,8,9]))
print(d)
# -> [5,8,9]
```

Can anyone help me in this case.

Comment: it's the way `filter` works. `filter(None, iterable)` is the same as `filter(bool, iterable)`. `bool(0)` is `False`

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) *"If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed."* `0` is `False`, so it's removed.

Comment: in the above filter method scenario, it will only return a value that is not zero. As zero is considered false in boolean terms. By this method, None can be removed but it will take 0 value too with it which you don't want, I assume.

Second Method (list comprehension)
The same can be done with a list comprehension. I assume you don't want to remove 0 but at the same time, you only want to remove any None value. In this case, a simple way can be as below.
d = [item for item in [0, None, 5,8,9] if item or item==0]
print(d)
 [5, 8,9]

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

> If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator expression ... `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is `None`.

And `0` is falsey.